# Power series expansion of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

How can I depict function
$f(z)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+z^2}}$ as a power series around zero?
Where Log is a function going from $C \setminus (-\infty,0]$?
Since with such a logarythm $Re(\sqrt{z}>0$ then I believe it would be enough to find a power series for real function $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}$
It could be done with sarting from $ \sqrt{1+x^2} $ and then just putting one series into another and finding a pattern but it is a pure mess.How can it be done nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  f(z) &= \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+z^{2}}} \\
  &= \sqrt{2+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}z^{2k}} \\
  &= \sqrt{2}
     \left \{
       1+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}
      \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{j}
        \left[
          \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k} \frac{z^{2k}}{2}
        \right]^{j}
     \right \} \\
  &= \sqrt{2}
     \left[
       1+\frac{z^{2}}{8}-\frac{5z^{4}}{128}+\ldots+
       (-1)^{n-1} \frac{(4n-3)!!}{(2n)!}
       \left( \frac{z}{2} \right)^{2n}+\ldots
     \right]
\end{align*}